# Issues with resolving promise on browser.findElements in Protractor

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to write a test in protractor(using jasmine and typescript) that tries to click on every link listed in a table. Before clicking on each link, I want the test to display the text of the link it is clicking on, and herein lies the problem. When I try to call .gettext() on the object containing all the elements, the ouput is about ManagedPromises. I have looked at other questions to try to resolve this, but in the end my solution looks similar to what I have seen. Here is my code below:

```
browser.findElements(By.xpath('//tBody//a')).then((clickLinks) => {
                console.log('made it [' + i + ']');
                console.log('link clicked[' + i + ']: ' + clickLinks[i].getText());
                clickLinks[i].click();
                i++;

                browser.waitForAngular();
                browser.driver.navigate().back();
                browser.waitForAngular();
            });
```

Comment: Could you please post what the output message is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is about `ManagedPromises` since the method `Elementfinder.getText()` returns a `Promise` object and not a `string` as you expect it. `getText()` is actually an `async` function and these functions always returns a `Promise`. A `Promise` can be considered as a wrapper for a value. It's a great concept for managing code. Please take your time and learn about  `Promise` Objects.

The other problem is, that
If you would like to output the text from the element you would have to call `getText().then(Func)` as follows:

```
browser.findElements(by.xpath('//tBody//a')).then((clickLinks) => {
  clickLinks[i].getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log('got text from link:', text);
  });
});
```

For example `browser.waitForAngular();` is also an async function. So your code would not work as you expect it to work.

If you write:

`browser.waitForAngular();
 browser.driver.navigate().back();`

These 2 functions would execute directly. Above code would correctly be written as follows:

```
browser.waitForAngular().then(function() {
  console.log('waitForAngular() done');
  browser.driver.navigate().back().then(function() {
    console.log('navigated');
  });
});
```

This looks a bit messy so they added the keyword `await` to `javascript` which is available within every `async` function. Above code in combination with `await` would look as follows:

```
async function waitForPage() {
  await browser.waitForAngular();
  await browser.driver.navigate().back();
}
```

hope I could help. Cheers!